# how to solve unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta' on python?

Tags: python

how to solve  unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta' on python?

I'm working to subtract -10 minutes from the current time.

### Referenced Documents

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

### Code attempted

```
import datetime

current_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.today(), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print("현재시간 : ", current_time)  # current_time = 20210813170951

current_time_minute10 = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
current_time_minute10 = datetime.datetime.strftime(current_time_minute10, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print("현재시간 : ", current_time_minute10)  # current_time_minute10 = 20210813165951

current_time_minute10_2 = current_time_minute10 - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
current_time_minute10_2 = datetime.datetime.strftime(current_time_minute10_2,
                                                     '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print("현재시간 : ", current_time_minute10_2)  # current_time_minute10_2 = 20210813164951

current_time_minute10_3 = current_time_minute10_2 - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
current_time_minute10_3 = datetime.datetime.strftime(current_time_minute10_3,
                                                     '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print("현재시간 : ", current_time_minute10_3)  # current_time_minute10_3 = 20210813163951
```

### error message occured

```
  File "[redacted]", line 10, in <module>
    current_time_minute10_2 = current_time_minute10 - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

---

### my goals

e.g : current_time = 20210813171700

current_time_minute10 = 20210813170700

current_time_minute10_2 = 20210813165700

current_time_minute10_3 = 20210813164700

### How can I continuously subtract 10 minutes from the current time like my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not convert your datetimes to strings (e.g. by using `.strftime`)

```
import datetime
         
current_time = datetime.datetime.today()
current_time_minute10 = current_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes= 10) 
current_time_minute10_2 = current_time_minute10 - datetime.timedelta(minutes= 10) 
current_time_minute10_3 = current_time_minute10_2 - datetime.timedelta(minutes= 10) 

print("현재시간 : ",current_time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')) # current_time = 20210813170951
print("현재시간 : ",current_time_minute10_2.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')) # current_time_minute10_2 = 20210813164951
print("현재시간 : ",current_time_minute10_3.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')) # current_time_minute10_3 = 20210813163951
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked out as I intended.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the initial `datetime` object value of `current_time_minute10` with a `str` type in the following line.

I don't know why you want the string value. But if it's only for printing, try this:

```
current_time_minute10 = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(minutes= 10)
print("현재시간 : ",datetime.datetime.strftime(current_time_minute10 , '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')) # current_time_minute10 = 20210813165951
```

Now you can use `current_time_minute10` in the next subtraction and the operation will be between `datetime` and `timedelta` objects, which won't raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: The reason you want to convert to a string is to import json data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a new variables for strings, like `current_time_string` apart from `current_time`

```
import datetime


current_time_string = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.today() , '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print("현재시간 : ",current_time_string) # current_time = 20210813170951





current_time_minute10 = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(minutes= 10) 
current_time_minute10_string = datetime.datetime.strftime(current_time_minute10 , '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print("현재시간 : ",current_time_minute10_string) # current_time_minute10 = 20210813165951





current_time_minute10_2 = current_time_minute10 - datetime.timedelta(minutes= 10) 
current_time_minute10_2_string = datetime.datetime.strftime(current_time_minute10_2 , '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print("현재시간 : ",current_time_minute10_2_string) # current_time_minute10_2 = 20210813164951





current_time_minute10_3 = current_time_minute10_2 - datetime.timedelta(minutes= 10) 
current_time_minute10_3_string = datetime.datetime.strftime(current_time_minute10_3 , '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print("현재시간 : ",current_time_minute10_3_string) # current_time_minute10_3 = 20210813163951
```